# Battery pack voltage measurement schematic for BQ769x0

Tags: adc

The datasheet of the BQ769x0 proposes the following schematic for measuring battery stack voltage.

[image]

What is the advantage of using two resistor bridges with the N-FET and P-FET instead of just using one resistor bridge and an N-FET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just had one N-channel MOSFET, the voltage on the analog input would rise to the battery voltage when it is "off", probably burning out your microcontroller.  With high-side switching, it drops to ~0 instead.  The leftmost divider limits the gate voltage on the P-channel to something safe when the N-channel is "on".  Gate voltage on the P-channel can be the same as source voltage with no issues.